# Global objects and their methods in ace editor

Tags: autocomplete, syntax-highlighting, ace-editor, code-completion

I have some global objects, which are pre-defined in code context (they are not explicitly defined in the current code, but can be accessed). And each of these global objects has some methods.

1. How can i add them to keywords (or somehow highlight them)?
2. How can i add them to auto-complete list?
3. How can i add methods of a global object to auto-complete list of the object (after typing ".")?

I'm using ace 1.2.0 with groovy and javascript modes.